# Consider the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the line x = 1.

Tags: calculus

Consider the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the line x = 1.

$x=y^2,x=1$
Find the volume V of this solid.

Sketch the region, the solid, and a typical disk or washer.

I have been following this example as a guide; however, I keep on getting the wrong answer.

$\pi\int\limits_{-1}^{1}{(1-y^2)^2dy}={16\over15}$

Any suggestions?

Comment: What happened to $\pi$?

Comment: I am sorry about the anwer in the other post, it should be ${16\over15}\pi$, I forgot to multiply the $\pi$.

Comment: It looks like you have deleted the other post so I will not be able to edit the answer there.

Comment: @BenCarson: Why do you think that it is the wrong answer?